# MVC 4 admin area within separate project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and would like to have my site admin area as an MVC Area within a separate project.

I've added a new MVC 4 Web Application project to my solution and added the following file to register my area:

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Admin"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "Admin", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Future.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

However this results in the following error:

```
A route named 'Admin_default' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.
```

I've altered the build output path of my admin area project to point to the main site project.

Is there something I'm missing or not configured?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this route is only declared once in your codebase, clean and rebuild your solution. This can happen if you have "old" dlls (for example if you had renamed a project) in your bin folder, with this route registered.

Comment: That sorted it! There was an old DLL in my bin causing problems. Thanks for your help.